# Creating a script element (from a script tag) to insert into the Head

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two script tags that I get from a trusted service.  It looks like this after I strip off the CDATA:

```
<script src="http://src1"></script><script src="http://src2"></script>
```

I need to insert these into the Head element.

If I do it like this examople below, it would work.  However, this means I need to parse the src attribute from both of the incoming script tags I mentioned above and create two new elements and add the src property to each element.  Which isn't what I want to do.

```
const head: HTMLHeadElement = document.querySelector("head");
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://sourcescript";
head.insertBefore(template, head.lastChild);
```

Is there not a way to make an HTMLElement directly from this HTML below?  This will avoid me having to parse the src attributes.

```
 <script src="http://src1"></script><script src="http://src2"></script>
```

Then I will insert that element into the Head like I did in the code above using insertBefore.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery can do this: `$("<html code here>")` should create the appropriate nodes. You'd still have to attach it yourself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to append the HTML with the scripts to a new element and then recurse its children and dynamically create new script elements with the `src` attributes of each child element. Then append them to the head:

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></scr'+'ipt><scr'+'ipt src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></scr'+'ipt>';

var script = e.firstChild,
    scriptInserted;

while(script) {
    scriptInserted = document.createElement('script');
    scriptInserted.setAttribute('src', script.getAttribute('src'));
    document.body.appendChild(scriptInserted);
    script = script.nextSibling;
}

// Test and see if jQuery and underscore js are loaded after a second.
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('jQuery', jQuery.fn.jquery);
    console.log('_', _.VERSION);
}, 1000);
```

I used `'<scr'+'ipt` syntax, because javascript confuses when a string contains `<script>` tags inside. You wont have a problem since you're getting the html with the scripts from a service.

And the console outputs:

[image: Dynamic scripts console]

You can check my working example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/append-script.html

Comment: fancy thanks.  I didn't want to loop but couldn't find another way.  So I used this technique